# How to use preg_replace with special symbols

Tags: php

I have problem with `preg_replace`. How to leave these symbols: `. , ? ! ' " : ;` and remove others? This function used with Lithuanian letters and numbers. I have tried this code:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s !?,;:.-]/u', '', $value);
```

Comment: Escape them?! Where is the problem?

Comment: the escape character for each of the items is a '\'

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape those characters that have a special meaning in regular expression in that case.

```
preg_replace ('/[^\.,?!\'":;\-]/', '' ,$value);
```

preg_quote can also be used:

```
$toKeep = preg_quote ('.,?!\'":;', '/');
preg_replace ('/[^' . $toKeep . ']/', '', $value);
```